# Not set activity for Campaign manager data transfer in Big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I created data transfer for Campaign manager in Big Query. I have an issue. I have a lot of activity dimension which are (not set)  in campaign manager. and I cannot see these data in my data transfer. any row which contains Activity=(not set) does not exist in my data transfer. could you please help if there is any solution to solve this issue and bring not set activity data?

thanks

I searched online. but I did not get any answers.